# TypesScript wrongly assumes that property is read-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple react component that I created with typescript and I encountered the following strange error. Here is my code.

```
interface State {
  value: string
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
  }

  changeHandler = (e: any) => {
    let state = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    state.value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          name="value"
          onChange={this.changeHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is the error that I got.

> error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a constant or a
>   read-only property.

This error got me thinking that perhaps this was typescript's way of enforcing the rule of not mutating state. To test this theory I did the following.

```
this.state.value = e.target.value
```

In this case I am clearly mutating state directly and sure enough I get the same error.

Then I had the idea of changing my interface to this.

```
interface State {
  value: Ivalue
}

interface Ivalue {
  value: string;
}
```

And then I refactored my component to use this new interface like this.

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: {
        value: ''
      }
    }
  }

  changeHandler = (e: any) => {
    let value = Object.assign({}, this.state.value);
    value.value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value.value}
          name="value"
          onChange={this.changeHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And sure enough this compiled! 
My question is really 2 questions. First, why was typescript not satisfied with my copy of state, like I have in my first snippet of code where I used `Object.assign`?
Second, why does nesting my state object one level further down solve this issue?

Comment: that would work. Same as doing `state[e.target.name] = e.target.value` would work. I just wanna know why the object.assign isnt enough tho.

Answer (score 2):

If the internal implementation (or TypeScript's understanding thereof) of `Object.assign` is to copy the object members' descriptors, and not just the field names, then it's copying the `readonly` attribute of your `state.value` and not just the keyname of your `state.value`.

I can't guarantee that's actually what's happening, as this would be news to me. But it's actually good news, and not bad news.

What versions of things are you using?

Also, you'll want to get into the habit of using the functional form of `setState`, if you're going to continue to use it through the next major release.

Comment: I used create-react-app to create this app so I cant see the version of typescript right, but I would guess it to be 2.3.4 or somewhere there

Comment: I just ejected its typescript 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite as:

```
changeHandler = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
}
```

or with [desctructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
changeHandler = ({target: {value}}: any) => {
    this.setState({value});
}
```

in Typescript you can mark your property as read-only. Is better way, because direct immutable state is not good pattern. You must run setState() function for change state.

Your props and state may look like this:

```
interface State {
   readonly value: string;
}
```

I mark with "readonly" all properties in types (for props, state, redux, etc). I want immutable pattern for all :)

Comment: Why not just `type State = { value: string }; const state: Readonly<State>;` TS 2.1 gives you a very useful generic constructor for exactly that, without having to write it everywhere.

Comment: I think that readonly in type definition is better. When I use `Readonly<T>`, I must write this statement very often.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the type definition for React's Component, you can see that the `state` property is defined as `Readonly<S>`, where `S` is the state type parameter.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L209